# PHP Function to output data from user

Tags: php, function

I have a profile.php page and I am calling the following function

```
function userData($id) {
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'");

     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        foreach ($row as $field) {
           $x = $field;
        }

        return $x;
     }
```

This obviously isn't working, but how would I make this function work so on the profile page i can just call:

```
userData('username');
```

or something similar to get the username of the profile id.

Comment: why isn't it working? what do you expect it to do VS what is it actually doing?

Comment: well nothing is happening, i am doing an echo userData('username'); and it's not working. also should the function have to parameters as I need to include id, should it be like userData($id, 'username'); I don't know what the best way to do this would be.

Comment: Warning mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc.. extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: So you are reading all the fields from the $row in $field....then assigning them to $x within a while loop and when the loop is over; returning $x. Which basically means you are returning the last read value of $field.......in other words; your code doesn't make any sense!

Comment: That's why I am asking for help lol, what should my function look like?

Answer (score 1):

Your query uses the parameter as an `id` yet you are calling the function while passing a `username`. Which is which?

Use this if you are going to use `id` as parameter:

```
function userData($id) {
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'");

  $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

  if($num_rows > 0){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array(sql);
    $x = $row['username'];
    return $x;
  }
  else{
    return "Empty";
  }

}
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Thanks for the heads up @Memor-X